# how to change label text color of the flutter material3 navigationBar widget?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I'm new to Flutter and working on a Material 3 app. I'm trying to customize the color of the selected label text in my BottomNavigationBar, but I'm running into some challenges.

Here's what I've tried so far:

I attempted to apply a TextStyle directly to the label text, but this didn't have any effect on the selected item's color.
I've also looked through the BottomNavigationBar's documentation, but I haven't found a straightforward property for modifying the selected label text color.
I'm hoping to achieve a specific color for the selected label text that stands out from the unselected items. I'm open to any guidance or suggestions on how to approach this in Material 3.

```
       bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        indicatorColor: HexColor('CEE7EF'),
        backgroundColor: HexColor('ffffff'),
        
        labelBehavior: labelBehavior,
        selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
        destinations: const <Widget>[
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.important_devices),
            label: 'Devices',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NavigationBarTheme(
      data: NavigationBarThemeData(
          labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
        const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      )),
      child: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentPageIndex = index;
          });
        },
        indicatorColor: HexColor('CEE7EF'),
        backgroundColor: HexColor('ffffff'),
        
        labelBehavior: labelBehavior,
        selectedIndex: currentPageIndex,
        destinations: const <Widget>[
          NavigationDestination(
            selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
            icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.important_devices),
            label: 'Devices',
          ),
          NavigationDestination(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```